# how do I pass a pointer variable where I can use it a different class?

Tags: c++, pointers, sdl

I have 2 classes one is a main class which is my gameloop and the other is an Enemy class where a wave of "enemies" spawn in. However I am having problems accessing my SDL window and renderer which are defined in the Enemy class. I know to use it in my Main class I have to pass the pointer variable to the window and renderer, this is the thing im struggling with. Any help on this?

my Enemy class

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;
#undef main

SDL_Window* window;
SDL_Renderer* renderer;

struct Enemy {
    void update() {
        x += 1;
    }
    void draw() {
        SDL_Rect healthBackground = { x,y,32,32 };
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 255, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &healthBackground);
    }
    int x, y;
};

struct EnemyManager {
    //simple function to create new enemy and add to the array of enemies
    void spawnEnemy() {
        Enemy e;
        e.x = 0;
        e.y = rand() % (480 - 32);
        enemies.push_back(e);
    }
    //simple update to update all enemies in array
    void update() {
        for (auto& e : enemies) e.update();
    }
    //draw all enemies in array
    void draw() {
        for (auto& e : enemies) e.draw();
    }
    //the main array of enemies
    std::vector<Enemy> enemies;
};

struct EnemyWaveManager {
    void update() {
        if (SDL_GetTicks() - lastSpawnTime > WAVE_SPAWN_TIME) {
            currentWave++; //increment wave by 1
            for (int i = 0; i < currentWave; i++) {
                em->spawnEnemy(); //create a new enemy
            }
            lastSpawnTime = SDL_GetTicks(); //reset timer;
        }
    }
    //spawn waves every 10s
    const int WAVE_SPAWN_TIME = 1000;
    long int lastSpawnTime = 0;
    int currentWave = 0;
    EnemyManager* em;
};
```

My Main class

```
#include "GameLoop.h"
#include "Enemy.cpp"

#undef main

//this can be accessed in any cpp file by adding "extern GameLoop * gameLoop"
GameLoop * gameLoop;


int main(int argc, char* args[])
{

    



    //construct a new gameloop object
    gameLoop = new GameLoop();
    if (!gameLoop->init()) {
        return 1;
    }

    //update and draw the game until quit by the user
    while (gameLoop->processInput()) {
        gameLoop->update();
        gameLoop->draw();
    }

    //perform any necessary cleaning up
    gameLoop->clean();

    //delete the gameloop object which has been allocated to memory.
    delete gameLoop;
    return 0;

    EnemyManager* em = new EnemyManager();
    EnemyWaveManager* wm = new EnemyWaveManager();
    wm->em = em;

    while (true) {
        SDL_Event e;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                return false;
            }

        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        em->update();
        wm->update();

        em->draw();

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        SDL_Delay(16);
    }


}
```

Comment: Files aren't the same as classes

Comment: `main` returns (by way of `return 0;`) before `EnemyManager* em = new EnemyManager();` and the rest of the enemy-related code is executed. None of the code you've shown actually runs.